# Testing JMS and Spring Integration

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration

I'm trying to write down a test class in order to test that a message driven channel adapter listening on a JMS Queue is forwarding the message to the right channel (ref. [Advanced Spring Integration Testing](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/advanced/advanced-testing-examples/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/advance/testing/jms/JmsMockTests.java)). Following is the test context xml:

```
<!--  MockRunner configuration  -->
    <bean id="destinationManager" class="com.mockrunner.jms.DestinationManager"/>

    <bean id="outgoingDestination" factory-bean="destinationManager" factory-method="createQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="demoMockRunnerQueue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="configurationManager" class="com.mockrunner.jms.ConfigurationManager"/>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.mockrunner.mock.jms.MockQueueConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="destinationManager"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="configurationManager"/>
    </bean>

    <!--  Spring JMS Template -->
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" />
    </bean>
```

Here is the spring integration configuration with the message driver channel:

```
<int:channel id="inbound"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
                                            channel="inbound"
                                            destination="outgoingDestination"
                                            connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                            acknowledge="transacted"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="inbound"
                            ref="messageQueueConsumer"
                            method="consumeMessage"/>

<bean id="messageQueueConsumer" class="uk.co.example.consumer.SimpleMessageConsumer">
    </bean>
```

And following there's the java class containing the test:

```
@Resource
JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

/**
 * "inbound" is the channel used to trigger the service activator (i.e. the message consumer)
 * */
@Resource
@Qualifier("inbound")
SubscribableChannel inbound;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(InboundChannelFlowUnitTest.class);

/**
 * This test verifies that a message received on a polling JMS inbound channel adapter is
 * routed to the designated channel and that the message payload is as expected
 *
 * @throws JMSException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Test
public void testReceiveMessage() throws JMSException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    String msg = "hello";

    boolean sent = verifyJmsMessageReceivedOnChannel(msg, inbound, new CountDownHandler() {

                @Override
                protected void verifyMessage(Message<?> message) {
                    assertEquals("hello", message.getPayload());
                }
            }
    );
    assertTrue("message not sent to expected output channel", sent);
}

/**
 * Provide a message via a mock JMS template and wait for the default timeout to receive the message on the expected channel
 * @param obj The message provided to the poller (currently must be a String)
 * @param expectedOutputChannel The expected output channel
 * @param handler An instance of CountDownHandler to handle (verify) the output message
 * @return true if the message was received on the expected channel
 * @throws JMSException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
protected boolean verifyJmsMessageReceivedOnChannel(Object obj, SubscribableChannel expectedOutputChannel, CountDownHandler handler) throws JMSException, InterruptedException{
    return verifyJmsMessageOnOutputChannel(obj, expectedOutputChannel, handler, 2000);
}

/**
 * Provide a message via a mock JMS template and wait for the specified timeout to receive the message on the expected channel
 * @param obj The message provided to the poller (currently must be a String)
 * @param expectedOutputChannel The expected output channel
 * @param handler An instance of CountDownHandler to handle (verify) the output message
 * @param timeoutMillisec The timeout period. Note that this must allow at least enough time to process the entire flow. Only set if the default is
 * not long enough
 * @return true if the message was received on the expected channel
 * @throws JMSException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
protected boolean verifyJmsMessageOnOutputChannel(Object obj, SubscribableChannel expectedOutputChannel, CountDownHandler handler,int timeoutMillisec) throws JMSException,
        InterruptedException {

    if (!(obj instanceof String)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only TextMessage is currently supported");
    }

    /*
     * Use mocks to create a message returned to the JMS inbound adapter. It is assumed that the JmsTemplate
     * is also a mock.
     */

    TextMessage message = mock(TextMessage.class);
    doReturn(new SimpleMessageConverter()).when(jmsTemplate).getMessageConverter();
    doReturn(message).when(jmsTemplate).receiveSelected(anyString());

    String text = (String) obj;

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    handler.setLatch(latch);

    doReturn(text).when(message).getText();

    expectedOutputChannel.subscribe(handler);

    boolean latchCountedToZero = latch.await(timeoutMillisec, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    if (!latchCountedToZero) {
        LOGGER.warn(String.format("The specified waiting time of the latch (%s ms) elapsed.", timeoutMillisec));
    }

    return latchCountedToZero;
}

/*
 * A MessageHandler that uses a CountDownLatch to synchronize with the calling thread
 */
private abstract class CountDownHandler implements MessageHandler {

    CountDownLatch latch;

    public final void setLatch(CountDownLatch latch){
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    protected abstract void verifyMessage(Message<?> message);

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see
     * org.springframework.integration.core.MessageHandler#handleMessage
     * (org.springframework.integration.Message)
     */
    public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
        verifyMessage(message);
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

But I get the following exception:

```
[0;33mWARN  [main] [InboundChannelFlowUnitTest] The specified waiting time of the latch (2000 ms) elapsed.
[m
java.lang.AssertionError: message not sent to expected output channel
```

Any hint on that?

**EDIT:**

I added the following test:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void testMessageDriven() throws Exception {
        TextMessage message = mock(TextMessage.class);
        when(message.getText()).thenReturn("foo");
        Session session = mock(Session.class);
        ((SessionAwareMessageListener<TextMessage>) this.messageListenerContainer.getMessageListener()).onMessage(message, session);
        CountDownHandler myCountDownHandler = new CountDownHandler() {
            @Override
            protected void verifyMessage(Message<?> message) {
                assertNotNull(message);
                assertEquals("hello", message.getPayload());
            }
        };
        CountDownLatch myLatch = new CountDownLatch(2);
        myCountDownHandler.setLatch(myLatch);
        this.inbound.subscribe(myCountDownHandler);

        boolean receivedBeforeZero = myLatch.await(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        assertTrue(receivedBeforeZero);
    }
```

And changed the message-driven adapter to:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
                                            channel="inbound"
                                            container="messageListenerContainer"
                                            acknowledge="transacted"/>
```

But still get the following error:

```
[0;33mWARN  [main] [InboundChannelFlowUnitTest] The specified waiting time of the latch (3 sec) elapsed.
[m
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:92)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:54)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message-driven adapter doesn't use a `JmsTemplate` so mocking it and its receive methods won't do anything.

You would have to mock/stub a message listener container and invoke its `MessageListener`. You can provide your mock container to the adapter via the 'container' attribute.

**EDIT**:

It's not entirely clear why you need to mock/test framework components; you can simply inject a test message into your flow by sending it to the channel.

However, if you are using custom message converters, and you want to test it in-place, you could mock the container.

[Here's how to do it](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/66c76847de1086cf2e795646da4b43a610041519).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gary. If I do this, then in the `verifyJmsMessageOnOutputChannel` method, do I still need to use the `CountDownLatch` and to subscribe the handler for the channel or I can just use the mock `jmsTemplate` to send message to the queue and the listener should pick it up?

Comment: Also I'm struggling trying to understand how to mock the listener container and invoking the MessageListener, is there any reference I can use?

Comment: Thanks Gary. I basically wanted to test that the message driven adapter is routing to the correct channel once the adapter detects message is received on the queue. I was under the assumption that to test this flow I had to simulate a message received by the listener.

Comment: Actually, I have updated my question with the new test and new error I'm getting. I don't want to manually receive the message from the channel but test that the correct channel received the message once the listener detected a message on the queue. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: Hi Gary, trying to follow your example I get an exception `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No poller has been defined for endpoint 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0', and no default poller is available within the context.`. I think this is because of the queueChannel defined as a queue without having a poller.

Comment: I used a `QueueChannel` so I could receive the message in the test; leave it as a `DirectChannel` if you want to invoke your service. It's still not clear what you are trying to test; since the message-driven adapter can only be configured with one channel; messages MUST go there.

Comment: Hi Gary, actually what I want to test is that receiving a message on the JMS Queue that the message listener is listening to will trigger the proper flow in Spring integration chain. So my first step was testing that the inbound channel is getting the message from the message-driven adapter.

Comment: There's little point in doing that; sounds like you should go straight to an integration test against your JMS broker.

Comment: Hi Gary, I'm quite new to JMS, do you have any reference about JMS broker integration tests? I'm using HornetQ embedded in a Tomcat instance. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73235/discussion-between-filippo-derosa84-and-gary-russell).